# Frequency of weekly days/hours in list of datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I want to count the number of days/hours in a list.
To answer this question: "How many events happened on Saturday 10AM ?"

```
from itertools import groupby, izip

import time
from datetime import date

 # Calculate number of events that happened 
d= ["2009-04-28 11:00:00 AM","2009-04-28 12:00:00 PM","2009-05-28 01:00:00 PM","2009-05-27 02:00:00 PM","2009-05-27 03:00:00 PM" ]


dt = [time.strptime(l, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')  for l in d]
cr_dates_i=[int('{0}{1:02d}'.format(c.tm_wday, c.tm_hour)) for c in dt]
counts = [(k, len(list(g))) for (k, g) in groupby(cr_dates_i)]
print counts


eg: 
2014-05-10 12:00:00 PM ==> Friday+12 ==> 512  (Sunday 0 - Saturday 6)
```

The question is: How can I affect now to every date, the number of frequencies ? with all possible events even zero cases.

Sunday(0)--> Saturday (6)

00:00 --> 23:00

As result, I should have (000, .. 623)

Answer (score 0):

So first I would define a function to translate datetimes to numbers like you expressed:

```
import time

def datetime_to_num(timestr):
    # convert string to time object
    dt = time.strptime(timestr, "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
    numday = (dt.tm_wday + 1) % 7 # get new day number
    numhour = dt.tm_hour # get hour number
    return int("{}{}".format(numday, numhour)) # return correct int
```

This will take a string of the form `2014-05-10 12:00:00 PM` and translate it to an integer from `0` to `623` as you described. If you want strings instead, so that you would have from `'000'` to `'623'` you could just remove the `int()` in the `return` statement, and everything should work essentially the same. Then you just need to count the frequency of those numbers somehow. So typically an easy way to do that is to use a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dtdict = defaultdict(int) # default count = 0

for dtstr in strlist: # for each string to process
    dtdict[datetime_to_num(dtstr)] += 1 # count it
```

You will then end up with a dict of frequencies of the form:

```
# for example:
{   '0' : 1,
    '1' : 3,
  '523' : 7,
  '623' : 4,
}
```

With any keys that are not present having a value of `0` when accessed.